# install iOS ad-hoc app failed

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I've a problem by installing an ad-hoc build to my iOS test devices.
When I run the app via XCode, there is no problem, but from the moment I create a signed ad-hoc app (*.ipa), the app is not able to install via iTunes or the iPhone configuration tool.

What I've done:
- Creating a distribution certificate 
- Creating an app ID (`com.project_name.*`)
- Creating a distribution provisioning profile including the distribution certificate, all devices UUID, etc.
- In the plist file I set "`Bundle identifer`" to "`com.project_name.app_name`"

By creating the ad-hoc file, I've chose the distribution certificate for code signing. This certificate is also set in the `project file --> build settings --> Code-Signing`

When I install the app in itunes, there comes an error dialog which just says, that it was not possible to install the app.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you are not using special characters in bundle identifier.

> The bundle identifier string identifies your application to the
>   system. This string must be a uniform type identifier (UTI) that
>   contains only alphanumeric (A-Z,a-z,0-9), hyphen (-), and period (.)
>   characters. The string should also be in reverse-DNS format. For
>   example, if your company’s domain is Ajax.com and you create an
>   application named Hello, you could assign the string com.Ajax.Hello as
>   your application’s bundle identifier. The bundle identifier is used in
>   validating the application signature.

If your bundle identifier is correct, 
Please validate your ipa file with following steps:

> Step1: rename yourapp.ipa to yourapp.zip
>
> step2: Extract content of yourapp.zip, you will see content in Payload
>   folder.
>
> Step3: locate yourapp.app in payload folder.
>
> Step4: rightclick on app and click "show package content"
>
> Step5: in package content, locate "embedded.mobileprovision"
>
> step6: Open "embedded.mobileprovision" in text editor. and check if
>   your device id exist there.

If your device id is there, Your build is correct. otherwise, rebuild by checking all code.

Note: Please make sure you have selected "Ad-hoc" while creating distribution file and not "App store".

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My device ID is included in the embedded.mobileprovision. But it still not work. The distribution provision profile is for ad-hoc packages. Du you have maybe another recommendation for my problem?

Comment: Pls check if there is any special character in your bundle identifier?  App installed on device if you have special character in bundle identifier when you run from Xcode..but dont allow you to install through any other medium if bundle identifier has special character in it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem wasn't the app.

**My solution:** Export the app as Xcode-Project (same way `Organizer --> Archive --> Distribute`) to another mac. Think about the certificates. You will have to export the private keys from your first mac too (*.p12 files). 
Open the XCode-Project from your second mac, sign it with the provision profile and install it via itunes.